How to specify the width of a QML HorizontalHeaderView to include the column title, and not just the data?
I'm using Qt Creator 13.0.0 and Qt 6.6.0 on Windows 11.
I have a Qt Quick project to simply display a custom table model that inherits QAbstractTableModel. I am using a TableView, which displays the actual data just fine. However, when I want to add column headers to the table, using HorizontalHeaderView, the column width is not expanded to include the full column name, so the text is cut off.
Here is a screenshot of the incorrect column widths. Notice it resizes to the data, but not the title.

Here is the header view. I tried defining a custom delegate (separate from the one it gets from syncView), as suggested in this question, but that didn't do anything.
    HorizontalHeaderView {
        id: horizontalHeader
        anchors.left: tableView.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        syncView: tableView
        clip: true
    }

And here's the TableView, if that helps.
    TableView {
        id: tableView
        anchors {
            left: verticalHeader.right
            top: horizontalHeader.bottom
            right: parent.right
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }

        clip: true
        columnSpacing: 1
        rowSpacing: 1

        selectionModel: ItemSelectionModel {}
        model: OrderBookData

        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: rectangleDelegate
            implicitWidth: txt.implicitWidth
            implicitHeight: 32
            border.width: 1
            Text {
                id: txt
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                leftPadding: 8
                rightPadding: 8
                text: display
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            }
        }
    }

Also note that when there are no rows in the table, the columns widths are perfectly fine.
